# How to run whole test suite with RobotFramework in several browsers at the same time through one command line in terminal?

Tags: testing, browser, terminal, automation, robotframework

How to run whole test suite in different browsers at the same time?

Comment: Natively that is not really easy to do and you might end up doing complicated things to achieve this. Could you elaborate your need? Why is that a problem to launch your test several times, once for each browser you want to test? You can merge the reports/logs after if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robot framework isn't designed to open several different browsers at the same time, or to run tests in parallel. If you want to test on five browsers, for example, the simplest solution is to run robot five times. You can do this with a powershell or bash script, or configure your continuous integration server to do it for you.

If you put the browser in a variable, you can set the value on the command line so that you don't have to modify your suites for each run.

For example, open the browser like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Suite Setup | Open Browser | ${ROOT} | browser=${BROWSER}
```

You could then create a script to run robot multiple times like this:

```
pybot --variable BROWSER:ff mysuite.txt
pybot --variable BROWSER:chrome mysuite.txt
pybot --variable BROWSER:safari mysuite.txt
```